# multiplication of 5 different size matrix in c ++

Tags: c++, matrix

I want to multiply 5 matrix ( all are not of same size) in c++, so what i can do?
will i have to use loop 5 times or is there any simple method like as in matlab?
sizes of matrix are 
1st : 1x4
2nd : 4x4
3rd : 4x4
4th : 4x4
5th : 4x1

Comment: You could create a Matrix class and provide `operator*`.

Comment: Look to see if there's already a library available to represent matrices.  If you're doing this for class/fun, you should start by thinking about a small class heiracrchy and maybe template params to specify the matrix size

Comment: @user1158692: hierarchy? what hierarchy?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan *Potentially* a base class and a derived template class, to allow the operator overloads to take references to the base.

Comment: @user1158692: I really believe that no inheritance should be involved here. Static polymorphism (templates) can provide sufficient genericity.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Maybe.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [boost linear algebra](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm) library which defines both matrix and vector types and has multiplication with `operator *`.

```
matrix<int>  m1(1,4);
matrix<int>  m2(4,4);
matrix<int>  m3(4,4);
matrix<int>  m4(4,1);

//... initialize your matrices here

matrix<int> result = m1*m2*m3*m4;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Write a function that performs the matrix multiplication for matrices of arbitrary size (with a sanity check).
2. Use the function four times, once for each multiplication.

Alternatively, you can define the `*` operator for the type matrix that you defined yourself, so that you could just write `a*b*c*d`